# helm multiline file inside range

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Im trying to create one secret with multiple file in it.

My value.yaml ( the format of the multiline is not yaml or json)

```
secretFiles:
  - name: helm-template-file
    subPath: ".file1"
    mode: "0644"
    value: |
      This is a multiline
      value, aka heredoc.
```

Then my secret file template is secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-template.fullname" . }}-file
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "helm-template.name" . }}
    chart: {{ include "helm-template.chart" . }}
type: Opaque
stringData: 
  {{- range .Values.secretFiles }}

  {{ .subPath}}: |
    {{  .value  | indent 4}}
  {{- end }}
```

The helm install gives error "error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 12: did not find expected comment or line break". How can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `indent` a line, you need to make sure the markup in the line starts at the very first column.

```yaml
stringData: 
  {{- range .Values.secretFiles }}
  {{ .subPath}}: |
{{  .value  | indent 4}}{{/* no space at start of this line */}}
  {{- end }}
```

In the form you have in the original question, the four spaces at the start of the line are copied to the output, then the `indent` expression adds four more spaces to the start of every line.  This results in the first line being indented by *eight* spaces, and the second line by 4, and that inconsistency results in the YAML parse error you see.

You'd also be able to see this visually if you run `helm template --debug` over your chart; you'll see the same error but also the template output that can't be parsed.

([@z.x's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74120725) solves the same problem a different way: putting the `-` inside the curly braces removes both the leading whitespace and also the preceding newline, and then changing `indent` to `nindent` puts the newline back.)

Answer (score 1):

values.yaml

```yaml
secretFiles:
  - name: helm-template-file
    subPath: ".file1"
    mode: "0644"
    value: |
      This is a multiline
      value, aka heredoc.
  - name: helm-template-file2
    subPath: ".file2"
    mode: "0644"
    value: |
      This is a multiline222
      value, aka heredoc.
```

xxx_tpl.yaml

```yaml
...
stringData: 
  {{- range .Values.secretFiles }}
  {{ .subPath}}: |
    {{-  .value  | nindent 4}}
  {{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
...
stringData:
  .file1: |
    This is a multiline
    value, aka heredoc.
    
  .file2: |
    This is a multiline222
    value, aka heredoc.
```

ref：

> [**nindent**](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#nindent)
> The nindent function is the same as the indent function, but
> prepends a new line to the beginning of the string.

> [**indent**](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#indent)
> The indent function indents every line in a given string to the specified indent width